# Work with an array of elements on the form (own class)

Tags: c#, .net, forms, class, frameworks

Good afternoon.
I started discussing this issue here, but I thought that the topic is worthy of a separate question, since I could not find the answer “from the swipe”.
[Panee was discussed at StaskOverflov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296496/delayed-action-while-holding-the-mouse-button-on-a-form-object-native-class/62299850#62299850)
Thanks to this decision, changes were made to the class ([new full code](https://github.com/rick1177/-Examples/raw/master/C%20%23/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/Seasonality_ProgressBar.cs)).

Now the changed type of the class is as follows:

```
    class Seasonality_ProgressBar : Control

 #region --События--
        public delegate void OnValueChangedEvent(int value);
        public event OnValueChangedEvent OnValueChanged;

#endregion

Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
MouseButtons mb = MouseButtons.None;

public int Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                if (value >= ValueMinimum && value <= ValueMaximum)
                {
                    _value = value;
                    Invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    value = _value;
                    Invalidate();
                }
                OnValueChanged?.Invoke(_value);
            }
        }

public Seasonality_ProgressBar()
{
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // base.OnMouseDown(e);
    if (!st.IsRunning)
    {
        mb = e.Button;
        st.Start();

        if (e.Button == mb)
        {
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}


 private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     timer.Stop();
     //MessageBox.Show("Сработало");
     float reultation = x - y;
     if (reultation > 0)
     {
         Value = "A";
     }
     else
     {
         Value = "B";
     }
 }
```

Now on the form you can subscribe to the event:

```
label2.Text = (-seasonality_ProgressBar1.Value).ToString();
seasonality_ProgressBar1.OnValueChanged += SomeEvent;
```

And the kind of SomeEvent method is:

```
private void SomeEvent(int value)
{
    //Use Invoke here because your event is called from another thread
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        label2.Text = (-value).ToString();
    }));
    //File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "seasonality_ProgressBar1_MouseUp\r\n");
}
```

@M. Artem, Thanks for the help.

My question is this.
On the form of elements of this class a lot (12 pieces). Each of them should display its own value on a separate label. I'm trying to learn how to create an array of elements of the same type on a form, while they are of their own class or standard (which, as I understand it, matters), i.e. you need 2 solutions, assign values to them, read values from fields that are not standard (my class has "author" fields).

Friends, help me learn, pliz.
Ready to answer all additional questions.

[image: form view]

ready to send any add-ons.

I’m new here, criticize, lower, dominate.

Comment: You can add existing ProgressBar to a List : List<Seasonality_ProgressBar> bars = new List<Seasonality_ProgressBar>() {progressBar1, progressBar2, progressBar3};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include this task in your custom control to show the value whenever it changes in a selected control.

➤ Add a new property of `Control` type, say:

```cs
class Seasonality_ProgressBar : Control
{
//...
    public Control ValueControl { get; set; }
//...
}
```

➤ In the setter of the `Value` property, check whether the `ValueControl` has a value and assign the `Value` property to it's `Text` property. You need to use the `Invoke` method here since you are using the `System.Timers.Timer` instead of the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`!

```cs
public int Value
{
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        if (value >= ValueMinimum && value <= ValueMaximum)
        {
            _value = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            value = _value;
            Invalidate();
        }
        if (ValueControl != null) Invoke(new Action(() => ValueControl.Text = value.ToString()));
        OnValueChanged?.Invoke(_value);
    }
}
```

➤ Rebuild.

➤ In the Form, select an instance of the `Seasonality_ProgressBar` and switch to the Properties window, you will see the new property listed as `ValueControl`.

➤ Select from the drop down the control that you want to connect it with this instance to show it's value. Say `label1`. Alternatively, you can set the `ControlValue` property in code:

```cs
seasonality_ProgressBar1.ValueControl = lable1; //or textBox1 ...etc.
```

➤ Run and try.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best!

Comment: @КириллГуреев Most welcome buddy and you are the kindest.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ProgressBar_Width = 100;
        const int ProgressBar_Height = 200;
        const int Label_Width = 10;
        const int Label_Height = 20;
        const int Number_Bars = 10;
        const int MARGIN = 20;

        List<Seasonality_ProgressBar> bars = new List<Seasonality_ProgressBar>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for(int i = 0; i < Number_Bars; i++)
            {
                Seasonality_ProgressBar bar = new Seasonality_ProgressBar();
                bar.Left = MARGIN + i * (ProgressBar_Width + MARGIN);
                bar.Top = MARGIN + MARGIN + Label_Height;
                bar.Width = ProgressBar_Width;
                bar.Height = ProgressBar_Height;
                bar.Name = "Bar_" + i.ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(bar);
                bars.Add(bar);

                bar.highLabel = new Label();
                bar.highLabel.Left = MARGIN + i * (ProgressBar_Width + MARGIN) + (ProgressBar_Width / 2);
                bar.highLabel.Top = MARGIN;
                bar.highLabel.Width = Label_Width;
                bar.highLabel.Height = Label_Height;
                bar.highLabel.Text = i.ToString();
                bar.highLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                this.Controls.Add(bar.highLabel);

                bar.lowLabel = new Label();
                bar.lowLabel.Left = MARGIN + i * (ProgressBar_Width + MARGIN) + (ProgressBar_Width / 2);
                bar.lowLabel.Top = MARGIN + MARGIN + ProgressBar_Height + Label_Height + MARGIN;
                bar.lowLabel.Width = Label_Width;
                bar.lowLabel.Height = Label_Height;
                bar.lowLabel.Text = i.ToString();
                bar.lowLabel.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                this.Controls.Add(bar.lowLabel);

            }


        }
    }
    public class Seasonality_ProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public Label highLabel { get; set; }
        public Label lowLabel { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. Judging by the code at the time of creating the form, you place all the components on it. And my question is this: if there is already a rendered form using the form designer, then at startup, is it possible to read the components on it into the array and change their properties in a loop, like the components of an array?

Comment: Yes : List<Seasonality_ProgressBar> bars = new List<Seasonality_ProgressBar>() { bar1, bar2, bar3};